# Unable to upload images to a specific folder in node.js using fileuploads

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

Below is the html for file upload

```html
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="Image">Image</label>
  <input type="file" name="image"  value="<%=fillData.image%>"  id="inpFile" class="form-control"placeholder="drop an image " /><br>
  <div class="image-preview" style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="" id="imgPreview" alt="imagePreview"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The server side code for handling the image uplaod in NodeJS using `fileupload` module

```js
router.post("/addProduct",(req,res)=>{
  const nimage = req.files.image.name
  const Price = parseFloat(req.body.price).toFixed(2)
  console.log(req.files.image)
  const nProduct = new Products({
    title:req.body.title,
    slug:req.body.slug,
    desc :req.body.description,
    category:req.body.category,
    price:Price,
    image:nimage
  })
  nProduct.save().then((value) => {
    mkdirp("public/product_images/"+nProduct._id).then(made=>{
      console.log(`file created starting with on id ${made}`)
    })
    mkdirp("public/product_images/"+nProduct._id+"/gallery").then(made=>{
      console.log(`file created starting with id and gallery  ${made}`)
    })
    mkdirp("public/product_images/"+nProduct._id+"/gallery/thumbs").then(made=>{
      console.log(`file created starting with  and thumbs${made}`)
    })
    if(nimage!=""){
      console.log("hello")
      const productImage = req.files.image
      const path = "public/product_images/"+nProduct._id+"/"+nimage;
      console.log(path)
      productImage.mv(path, function(err){
        return console.log(err)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Getting the following error

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\NodeE\public\product_images\5ff718bebe310d2f3c34590a\noimage.jpg'] {
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: 'D:\NodeE\public\product_images\5ff718bebe310d2f3c34590a\noimage.jpg'
> }

Comment: is in your pc `D:\NodeE\public\product_images\5ff718bebe310d2f3c34590a\noimage.jpg` exists?

Comment: `mkdirp()` is async you have to wait for it to complete in order to move files to it, ie move the moving code into the `then()` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using mkdirp synchronously, while it's an asynchronous operation.

Either move all your code inside `then(made=>{ ... })` or use async await.

```
router.post("/addProduct",async (req,res)=>{
  const nimage = req.files.image.name
  const Price = parseFloat(req.body.price).toFixed(2)
  console.log(req.files.image)
  const nProduct = new Products({
    title:req.body.title,
    slug:req.body.slug,
    desc :req.body.description,
    category:req.body.category,
    price:Price,
    image:nimage
  })
  
  await nProduct.save();

  await mkdirp("public/product_images/"+nProduct._id);
  await mkdirp("public/product_images/"+nProduct._id+"/gallery");
  await mkdirp("public/product_images/"+nProduct._id+"/gallery/thumbs");

  if(nimage!=""){
    console.log("hello")
    const productImage = req.files.image
    const path = "public/product_images/"+nProduct._id+"/"+nimage;
    console.log(path)
    productImage.mv(path, function(err){
      return console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the `then`'s so that you are writing to the directory only after it is created

Eg.

```js
mkdirp(...)
  .then(made=>{
    // write to directory here
  })
```

Or if you want to write after creating all the directories use

```js
Promise.all(mdirp('...'), mdirp('...'), mdirp('...'))
  .then(made=>{
    // write to directory here
  })
```